# How could my characters be tricked into thinking they are on Mars?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, space-colonization

In the not-so-distant future, a corporation announces their plan to turn a colony on Mars into a competition-reality show. This is a believable claim, because others have already colonized Mars, but they are all small groups of astronauts sent on research missions. This is the first private venture to put ordinary people on Mars, and it will supposedly be funded by revenue from the show.

However, the makers of the show never intend to send their colonists to Mars. Instead, they take them to a Mars-like habitat on Earth, where they film them and then edit the footage so it appears to be taking place on Mars. They send an empty rocket ship into space, which is aired on TV. They are pocketing the money from the show.

So here are my questions:

1. How could the colonists be tricked into thinking they traveled to Mars?

The journey takes about 9 months. Will they be frozen for this entire duration? Or will they be taken to the set straight away, under the impression they have been in cryo for 9 months? If the latter, they could begin filming immediately, but there would need to be a lag of 9 months before the public sees the footage. How could the producers explain this time lag to the colonists? Either way, how are they transported across Earth without raising the suspicions of the public? Won’t the colonists wonder why they didn’t awaken on a ship?

2. How could the colonists be tricked into thinking they are on Mars?

The habitat is the HI-SEAS simulated Mars habitat on a Hawaiian volcano. The area is isolated and the terrain resembles Mars, but several factors still need to be accounted for. First, the sand/sky would not have the reddish tinge Mars is famous for. Is it plausible to have the colonists wear red-tinted space helmets when they are outside? Any windows would also be tinted red. This would be obvious but because it’s also a TV show, colonists and viewers could be convinced it’s for effect. Second, the day is shorter on Earth than on Mars. How could the colonists be unaware that sunrise/sunset are not as expected? Could strict curfews and blackout shades do the job? Any other suggestions? Third, the temperature will be significantly warmer on Earth than on Mars. The spacesuits will prevent the colonists from feeling the heat, but is it plausible that the thermometers have been altered to read a lower temperature? Lastly, how could a weaker gravity be simulated?

I’m sure there are other issues I missed. Overall, how can colonists be convinced they are on Mars, and are my explanations for Earth/Mars phenomena plausible? Have I overlooked anything?

Note that over the course of the story, the colonists will slowly discover that something is awry, so it’s okay if the set is not foolproof.

Comment: The day is only a little longer on Mars than on Earth (24 hours 40 minutes), not enough difference to be noticeable by a person without a clock. On the other hand, gravitational acceleration on Mars is two and half times lower than on Earth; people will notice the difference in a heartbeat.

Comment: You're also going to need buy-in from space agencies on Earth and those colonizing  Mars, because  they'll be able to trivially see that your colony is not where you say it is using whatever satellite equipment they have to support their own Martian operations.

Comment: @AlexP Easy, select people for the "journey" that don't know about that factoid. In fact, most people don't.

Comment: This is pretty easy. Just reduce gravity by 50%, evacuate the outside of all its atmosphere, change the color of the sky. You know, the stuff you have the production interns do for their filmmaking capstone credits, don't even have to pay them. Also, see if you can recruit OJ Simpson for it for some celebrity ratings boost.

Comment: Is it just the colonists who need to be fooled? Or the viewers too?

Comment: If the audience are in on it and the only people to be fooled are the participants, then this sounds like a more elaborate version of a show that actually happened on UK TV https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Cadets_(TV_series)

Comment: Not enough for a full answer, but you can tell them that they'll be wearing weighted uniforms for the duration of their stay on Mars, to simulate Earth gravity and prevent muscle loss. Of course, these uniforms don't weigh nearly as much as the participants think they do. Granted, bathing would be an issue...

Comment: @WiggotheWookie the audience does need to be fooled. But that is easy, it can be done in the post-edit. The real challenge is fooling the “colonists”.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger that is a great solution. I would consider it.

Comment: @TheresaKay Additionally, making everyday objects lighter would supplement the illusion. Wouldn't help with fall time, but that's not what most people would notice first.

Comment: They can't: thre's no possible way you could fake the gravity. This is in an era where footage of real Martian colonists is commonplace, so everyone will know what bouncing around in Martian G looks like. (And these are presumably people with some interest in going to Mars, so it's not like they'll never have seen it on TV/YouTube.) So they'll know in seconds that they're not on Mars and there's nothing you could possibly do about that.

Comment: @TheresaKay One of the ways they used to fool the participants in Space Cadets was selecting easily influenced people who had no prior interest in space or sci-fi so they were easy to fool, so this wouldn't work if you also need to fool the watching world...

Comment: The only way this could possibly work is if you are sending uneducated idiots to be your astronauts as faking lower gravity is basically impossible

Comment: Possible research - see the TV miniseries Ascension from about 8 years ago.

Answer (score 31):

## Things you’ve missed

There’s no way to fake this for an educated audience - the only people you could possibly fool will be the performers. Even then, you’ll have some major problems, especially if the crew is ever allowed outside (and since you mention the sky, I assume they are)

#### Atmosphere:

Earth has one, with various giveaway side effects

- tangible wind
- Clouds
- Air resistance when dropping objects or moving
- Fog
- Literally all weather phenomena

### Life:

Mars is notoriously absent of life. Hawaiian islands are not.

- Birds fly by
- insects live in the ground
- Primates in rudimentary flying machines pass overhead
- Plants. Plant life persists at up to 21,000 feet, so the 8200 of HI SEAS will be rife with it.
- Plants 2. Their view will have plenty of plant life at lower elevations.

### Other:

- Earth’s moon overhead will be a dead giveaway
- There’s really no practical way to imitate gravity

Comment: Gave you thumbs up. There's more. The sun from Mars is noticeably smaller and provides less heat. Mars has two moons that would be visible, though much smaller than our one. And if they're even vaguely up on astronomy, they will miss Earth in the sky.

Comment: You also need to simulate speed-of-light comms lag, although that is far easier than the moon or gravity. Nonetheless, any slip-up will be a serious problem.

Comment: @JohnDallman: Introducing such an artificial delay would be dead easy compared to the other hurdles.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Absolutely. But a slip in doing it will be a dead giveaway.

Comment: Mars does have an atmosphere with (rather lively) weather, although it's very different from our Earth weather. Martian wind, dust devils, and sandstorms are well-known for their impact on various rovers, most famously *Spirit* and *Opportunity*.

Comment: @Cadence Mars' atmosphere is not, however, able to sustain clouds, and the 'windstorms' at their fastest exert about as much force as a light breeze does on earth.

Comment: @BobaFit Not just Earth. There was a story for which this was a spoiler:  a guy claimed to have been on Mars many times, and plausibly claimed to have seen Earth, Venus, and Mercury in the sky. But someone realized that the guy never mentioned seeing the Moon, which is almost as big as Mercury and should be glaringly obvious near Earth.

Answer (score 16):

**Choose your colonists wisely**

As some commentators already noticed, difference between Earth and Mars gravity should be a dead giveaway for this attempted ruse. Other factors like sky which must be very different, air pressure and nighttime temperatures which must be much lower would leave virtually no room for tricking anyone on Earth who spend minimum effort on researching Mars.

What do you do? You select your candidates very carefully. They should only be vaguely aware of all of those differences, and during their training, you do not let them know what to expect of the *real* Mars. Thus, when arriving at the martian base (actually located in some earthly desert) they could be led to believe that this is the actual Mars. They should go out of this base only in spacesuits and for a short time, believing that they can't breath the air outside. In case if someone gets suspicious about the gravity, it can be explained away by this idea that human bodies are becoming weaker in space, so you feel just normal on Mars and can't pull any of John Carter's tricks.

Comment: Yes - these are the lines I was thinking along. The training involves more about acting on camera and less about survival, so colonists don’t know what to expect on Mars. Particularly, the protagonist is being heavily watched by the producers because he questions everything, and they fear he will blow their cover. But they need him for his “skills” which is why they keep him.

Comment: @TheresaKay What skills do they need him for? They should have production staff for anything that actually needs doing, aside from acting. (And even if your actor is a fully qualified X and wants to show off for the camera, you should keep a backup or two around just in case; that's just basic filmmaking.)

Comment: This is the first time I've seen "John Carter knowledge" used as an advantage.

Answer (score 9):

You've suggested two ways the time lag for travel could be covered -- delaying broadcast nine months has the advantage that you have time to CG things if needed to keep up the illusion and makes it easy to insert the extra half hour plus per day to keep "Sols" the correct amount out of sync with Earth days.

"Colonists" not waking on the ship would be covered by having the "cryopods" designed to be opened after landing -- "so the lander only needs life support for the pilots" or similar excuse.  Red tints on visors etc. could also be done with VFX technology, with the colonists told their "acclimation drugs" alter their color perception so the habitat lighting, adjusted to match Mars color palette, and the outside light will look white.

The things you *cannot* convincingly fake with anything close to today's technology are gravity and atmosphere.  The gravity at the habitat, inside and out, will be roughly 2.5 times what it would be on Mars, and telling the "colonists" they've "lost that much muscle tone in cryosleep" won't change the fact that stuff *falls too fast*.  And the atmosphere outside is *breathable* (though someone from sea level conditions will be uncomfortable immediately -- ear pain and shortness of breath, possibly lightheadedness, especially if exerting) -- a "space suit" breach won't lead to death in minutes; instead they'd survive for any reasonable time frame breathing the outside air -- there might even be plants growing in locations visible from the habitat or EVA paths.  The elevation of the HI-SEAS Mars simulation hab isn't so high that, for instance, rocks have no lichen growth (nor even is that of the Mauna Loa Observatory at half again the height).

So, while this kind of "Earth for Mars" setup might be good enough for a controlled and post-produced drama, there is no way it could maintain a long term secret.  Likely the first time someone tossed something into the air, or something or someone fell on camera, the jig would be up.  Unless the video is being shown only to people with very poor or no science education...

And then there's the fact that that habitat *has been on TV* and some of the colonists (who are presumably at least a little interested in space, else they wouldn't be there) might recognize stuff they've seen before.  "We copied all this stuff from that old NASA experiment to save time and money" is a pretty thin excuse along with all the other stuff...

Comment: HI-SEAS is in about 2000m above sea level. nobody will fall unconscious there or even feel uncomfortable.

Comment: Ah, I'm confusing it with the observatory on Mauna Loa, at around 4500 m.  Where there's still plant life and people live for weeks or months at a time.

Comment: Er, yeah, 3400 m.  I've skied almost that high.

Comment: To fake low gravity: make every piece of equipment magnetic, and include big magnets in the ceilings of every room. Insist the participants wear spacesuits at all times. The spacesuits are magnetic too, of course.

Comment: Won't work, @Stef -- the magnetic attraction increases as you get closer to the magnets.  Too far, an there's nothing; too close and your stuff "jumps' to contact the magnet.

Comment: @ZeissIkon But the distance to the magnets should be relatively constant, since the magnets are in the ceiling and the participants are on the ground. The magnets should be calibrated such that at this distance, they compensate the gravity somewhat, but not completely, since Mars still has a gravity, albeit lower than Earth's.

Comment: @stef It won't work.  you're free to experiment for yourself, but it won't work, else we'd use maglev a lot more on Earth.  It requires active control to get a constant force from magnets.  Otherwise, stuff will be much heavier to lift off the floor than it is to hold, and if you lift it over your head, it might just fly out of your hands.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Okay. New plan. The objects are not magnetic - they're just made of light material that makes it look heavier than they are, so it feels like the objects are under lighter gravity. The only magnetic things are the spacesuits. Could this work?

Comment: @stef still nope, stuff will still fall faster than it should.  And a suited "colonist" who manages to jump high enough (or climbs on anything) will still stick to the ceiling.

Answer (score 7):

Be the camouflage for an Actual Mission to Mars whose purposes need to be kept Secret.

You're not going to fool anyone with a fake mission to Mars. People will come to watch your launch.  Launches, actually, you're going to need to throw a log of equipment to Mars to keep humans alive, and you're unlikely to be able to do that on a single launch. So you'll need lots of different moving parts, regulatory agencies, space agencies, governmental and industrial support, and sponsorships. Even after multiple short-term colonization,  there's going to be enough  people in the chain that the kayfabe is practically guaranteed to break  if you don't *actually* send a Mars Mission.

So send one. Cooperate with a sufficiently secretive but well-funded Nation State who has some plot-required Secret Reason to put boots on Mars, but absolutely doesn't want people knowing what their people are doing on Mars. So there will be a Mars Base to be observed  by other nations and space agencies, and there will be matching surface operations and EVAs that are explained by your recruited rubes so that nobody looks too closely.  And it's Mars, so presumably the chosen landing location cannot be reached overland on a whim by the people already there.

The kayfabe is likely to still break. But by then , the Nation-State's will presumably have retrieved/assembled/conquered/had their crew be slain by whatever they *actually* went to Mars to do, and the rest of the World probably has something more important to grab their attention than potential lawsuits from your recruits.

Comment: Would make one hell of a story

Comment: Do you suggest to actually send those people there? If not, how do you convince them they are there?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Space Cadets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Cadets_(TV_series))

They were able to convince the selected cadets that they were on the Space Shuttle, even though it had gravity. You could fool people to say they were on Mars, particularly if you pick the right people, but I do not think this would make a good Science Fiction story.

How long does the plot need before they find out? Is it months or years? I can probably get you two weeks...

They travel in 'suspended animation'. They wake up slowly in a crowded capsule that has already landed after 'their 'nine month journey'. They have a long list of things to do to unpack and assemble their habitat.

They are told they will be weakened by having no gravity for 9 months. Mars has one-third gravity but it will feel like full earth gravity to start with (thanks [Alexander](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/32451/alexander) for that).

The day is very similar to that on Earth. They keep 'Earth-like' hours. Their stay starts when the moon is waxing, so it appears at night when they are asleep.

They start off bring tightly packed in their capsule. It is not easy to see that things are falling more slowly if they cannot stand back and have a look. Most of the capsule should be rigged for zero-G so everything has a place, and things should not fall. The floor should be padded, so if anything was dropped, it would not fall with an obvious 'thump' that might get them thinking.

If they were high up somewhere, the sky out of the window would link unfamiliar, if not exactly like Mars. They should have filters in the windows. They would probably not notice the actual difference in light level, but the size of the sun would be a giveaway. Maybe the capsule could have 'fish-eye' lenses, for 'all-round seeing', so they do not see the true angular size of anything.

That might give you two weeks, with some people arguing that things were falling slowly, and other saying they were not, until the moon rises.

Answer (score 4):

I have a bit of a frame challenge, because you're not thinking like a TV producer.

##### Plot twist: reality TV is staged.

The basic premise is fairly simple to set up. **[You wake up in a room](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouWakeUpInARoom).** This is an old trope, but there's no reason it can't work. You "sedate" the contestants, and then they wake up, an indiscriminate amount of time later, somewhere else. **You say they're on Mars.** Put them in a locked habitat, inside a sound stage with a convincing backdrop.

Why should anybody doubt you? The audience? Oh but the audience knows, that's part of the draw: watch 12 idiots tricked into thinking they're on Mars when in reality they're somewhere on a stage in the Greater Los Angeles Area.

The gravity? Oh, their body adapted while they were sedated, that's why they don't feel the difference. Nobody knows what Mars gravity is supposed to feel like, and who's going to run experiments to calculate $g$ anyways?

It's all shot on a sound stage obviously, maybe even an [on-set virtual production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-set_virtual_production) stages. That way you can have a complex simulation of the outside that works from a fixed viewport or two. Nobody's going outside anyways. The airlock is sealed, they have no suits, whatever you need to keep them inside. You wouldn't get good footage out of it anyways.

**Use story editing** to craft the narrative that these are clueless colonists trapped on Mars, and then reveal to them it was all a trick at the end. Reality TV may not be scripted, but it's edited. If you film people long enough, you'll get footage that you can take out-of-content to tell any story you want. You decide when they start getting suspicious, if at all, through clever editing and a good voice over.

Nobody is going to question the time between production and broadcast. That's just TV baby. That way you don't have to worry about something unavoidable contradicting the story so far, or you can quickly throw in a cooking show to fill the timeslot if someone actually dies for real. Remember, *Survivor* isn't live, although you could certainly edit it that way.

And obviously, **pick your contestants**. The best decision you can make is to pick professional contestants. The kind of people who make a career out of appearing in reality TV shows, who know which part of their character to amplify to please producers and advertisers. They could even be in on the fact they're not on Mars, and they'll play along because they know it's in their best interests. In fact, you'll probably get the best material if they're in on it. They're professionals after all.

##### Who are you tricking anyways?

The only people you have to trick is your audience. Not the audience of the show in the story, *your audience*, the actual people reading the story. See, much like reality TV, your story is edited, with a narrator, telling things nobody can verify. What a twist that the narrator was lying to you all along.

Answer (score 3):

**Your participants are hypnotized.**

[image: hypmopized]

[source](https://www.bodylanguagesuccess.com/2016/01/nonverbal-communication-analysis-no_2.html)

They think they are on Mars.  Really they are in Hawaii.  But they are totally hypnotized and so Mars takes place in Hawaii.

The audience figures it out 10 minutes into the show.  It is a very funny show.  The corporation was originally going to try to fake people out but the production crew kept cracking up at how silly it is.  The company realizes they have come up with something good and they roll with it.

The cast comes out of their hypnosis at the end.  They are very embarrassed but they are also very famous.  Many of the same cast go to "Saturn" in season 2.

Comment: I don't think hypnosis really works like this...

Comment: @user132647 - could it be you are hypnotized to think that?

Comment: Reminds me of Total Recall

Comment: @Willk: Unlikely, but not impossibe. :) Hypnosis is often portraited in the way you do in stories, so your idea might work great for a story, therefore this is not a bad answer. Hypnosis does not work like this in real life, but it does work like this in stories and entertainment.

Answer (score 3):

With a little handwaving on the exact technology used, I think you can solve a number of the listed problems.  You need to create your own habitat rather than use an existing one and encase it in a giant dome.

1. No plants or animals - during construction, you burn away any existing plants & remove all insects, birds & animals from the dome
2. Red tint - you can project your "sunlight" from the top of the dome in whatever shade you want.
3. No wind, clouds or atmospheric disturbances - no wind inside the dome and you can project whatever skyscape you want, including accurate Mars stellar maps at night and two moons that rise and set
4. Adjust the length of the day - by extending the time between your night & day cycles you can get an accurate Mars-day
5. Atmosphere - you could change the mixture of air in the dome (outside the living habitats) to reduce the amount of oxygen available.  Any colonist who gets a tear in their suit would get immediate effects.  (see note)
6. In fact, you could slightly adjust the oxygen within the habitat & the suits, and that would make any action feel like it is harder.  It wouldn't directly simulate the effect of higher gravity but if people get tired quicker from doing simple tasks, you could probably convince them that was the cause.(see note)
7. Temperature - keep the atmosphere in the dome colder and the colonists will notice some difference between being in the habitat & being outside in the suit.  Or you can simply rig the spacesuits to slowly lower their own temperature when worn/sealed.

The biggest problems I see with this are the quality of the projection for the "outside" and stopping the colonists from getting too close to the walls of the dome, where they will probably notice issues long before they actually touch them.
However, if you make the "windows" on the habitat and the helmets of the spacesuits appear pitted, scratched & blurred the colonists are less likely to notice any projection issues.  And you can tether the spacesuits to the habitat in some way so the colonists cannot go too far from the center of the dome.

*Note - messing with atmosphere might not be ethical, but given the premise of totally fooling the colonists, I'm not sure this will worry your production company too much.

Comment: "It wouldn't directly simulate the effect of higher gravity" - Mars has lower gravity than Earth, not higher.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in the length of a day would be easy to work around. Just give them rigged clocks that make it look like a longer day. And of course replace any watches or other time-keeping devices that colonists bring with similarly rigged devices.

The atmosphere would be only a minor problem. You tell them it's not breathable, so no one tries to go outside without a space suit on. Then how would they know that they don't really need the spacesuits? You say they eventually figure it out. Okay, a big clue could be when someone gets a tear in his spacesuit or breaks the face of his helmet and he doesn't die, but finds he can breathe the "Martian" air quite easily.

If you tell them that they're in cryo sleep or some such for the trip, then there wouldn't have to be any great mystery for the arrival on "Mars". Just mock up a fake spaceship for them to wake up in and put it in your simulated Mars. You can tow it there in a truck, it won't matter if everybody is unconscious until after the "landing".

Fooling the audience should be easier than fooling the participants, as you can edit up any footage with CGI or whatever to cover up flaws.

Hiding moving the subject around on Earth wouldn't be that big a deal. Yeah, you don't load them all on a bus with "Fake Mars Trip" painted in big letters on the side. But if you move them in vans with "Joe's Plumbing Service" painted on the side, who's going to notice?

Maybe some intrepid reporter would get a tip about the fake and track it down. That all depends on how well you keep a secret. On the minus side, a lot of people would have to be in on the secret, and that makes it more likely that somebody would give it away, accidentally or deliberately.

Other things would be tougher.

I doubt the difference in sky color could be solved by simply tinting spacesuit visors. Wouldn't someone who picks up a helmet inside notice that the visor is tinted? They'd have to put on the helmet in the airlock. Wouldn't they notice that the color of everything in the airlock changes? Maybe, possibly, you could have some technologically more sophisticated visor that changes color only when they look outside. Working out the details of how that would work would be tricky, but maybe doable.

What happens if when they go outside they see plants? Or see birds flying overhead? That would be a quick giveaway. Maybe you could have a team go through and exterminate all the plants and insects before the "mission" begins. But how could you prevent birds from flying over? Or maybe even some larger animal wandering into "Mars"?

Maybe they'd notice that air resistance when they drop or throw something is much greater than it should be. Would the average person notice that or think about it? Likewise, would they notice that things blow in the wind in a way that wouldn't happen on Mars?

The difference in gravity would, I think, be the toughest thing to fake. Even if the people in the game aren't physicists, if they have any clue that Mars gravity is dramatically lower, you'd think they'd notice that gravity in their habitat is Earth normal. A sufficiently smart person might measure the speed at which things fall and prove it. But even someone of somewhat below average intelligence should find himself saying, "Hey, I thought the gravity here was supposed to be less. But it seems normal."

Oh, I would suggest NOT using an existing simulated Mars habitat. Find some other location and build your own. If you use an existing one, there's the possibility that one of the subjects will recognize it. And it's virtually certain that some number of viewers of the program will recognize it. Plus, habitats used in experiments are not designed to fool the participants into thinking they're really on Mars, but to reproduce conditions well enough to be a useful experiment. They don't try to fake the sky or ground color, etc.

You might be able to get away with more mistakes if the subjects are carefully chosen for NOT being particularly scientifically literate or savvy. Would anyone wonder, "Why did they choose all dumb people?" I'd guess not. Most people think they're pretty smart. "I may not have dem book learnun, but I's is pretty clever."

Answer (score 2):

**Make your story a comedy.**

That way, it's just funny when your colonists fail to notice all the little discrepancies (atmosphere, sky, plant and animal life, planes flying overhead), and the audience doesn't go "wait, they should have noticed--". The colonists' space suits can be attached to wires when they go outside so they fall more slowly, even as dropped objects fall at the normal speed.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers have focused on red tinted visors for space suits. That makes a landscape without ANY living things look right, but doesn't help much for clouds, aircraft, etc. I would submit that virtual reality technology could be used to edit out these unwanted features from your marsnauts' visors and habitat windows. Visors and windows against hostile and/or low pressure environments can be expensive. So if you feel like display technology can never be high enough resolution to fool reality, then your "corporation" can be being too cheap to have real visors and use video screens instead. Or the graphical indicators overlaid on VR background are so busy that user is distracted from noticing that the background is not real.

For simulating launch, you can probably get away with just tilting and shaking the room. Room is tilted up and shaken to simulate pulling g's during launch. And then vibration reduces and tilts forward to simulate gravity slipping away. You'll have to knock out yours marsnauts before reaching orbit because you won't be able to fake true weightlessness unless you put them on an airplane and fly in [zero g parabolic arcs](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/research/kc135.html). Even then you only get 20 to 25 sec of free fall.

If there are already marsnauts in your fake habitat, they can help make the illusion stronger by being around to explain things and reinforce the narrative.

Answer (score 0):

Frederick Pohl used this idea in Mars by Moonlight, Galaxy Science Fiction 1958, which is set in a penal colony on Mars. There is no need for guards, since there's no way to escape, and the convicts have had their memories of the crime erased. Only none of this is real: the "convicts" can't remember their crimes because, in reality, they didn't commit them; they are somewhere in a desert in the US; and they have been carefully selected to make sure that they know nothing about Mars (e.g. how many moons there are supposed to be, whether the atmosphere is breathable, etc); that was easier in 1958 than in 2022.
I suggest that you read the story before going further.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll look into that.